# MySQL pivot table - NOT IN

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

In a MySQL database I have the following tables:

**customers**

```
CUSTOMER_ID | NAME
---------------------------
1           | John Doe
2           | Peter Jones
3           | David Smith
```

**products**

```
PRODUCT_ID  | DESCRIPTION
---------------------------
1           | Toothbrush
2           | Shaving cream
3           | Deodorant
```

**customer_product**

```
CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT_ID
---------------------------
1           | 2
1           | 3
2           | 1
3           | 1
3           | 2
```

The table **customer_product** is a pivot table. When a customer orders a product, it will be logged there.

My question is: how can I select all customers that didn't ordered a certain product?

So for example, I want to retrieve all customers that never ordered a Toothbrush.

Comment: I think `customer_product` is properly called a "mapping" table, not a "pivot" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,NAME
FROM customers AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM customer_product AS cp
   INNER JOIN products AS p
      ON cp.PRODUCT_ID= p.PRODUCT_ID
   WHERE p.DESCRIPTION = 'Toothbrush' AND cp.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: `cp`: `INDEX(CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that will work for you

```
select c.customer_id,c.Name from  customers c
where c.customer_id not in
(select c.customer_id from  customers c
left join customer_product cp on c.customer_id = cp.customer_id
inner join products p on cp.product_id = p.product_id
where p.description ='toothbrush'
) ;
```

Comment: Works as well. Thank you

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is likely to be faster than `NOT IN ( SELECT ...)`